# この曲の意味を暗示する歌詞の特定性について

Tags: history, song-lyrics, music

念のため述べておきますが、この質問は太平洋戦争に関係するものであり、気分を害するつもりは一切ありませんが、その可能性のある内容が含まれています。

とある日本のロックバンド、「9mm Parabellum Bullet」が2007年に「Sundome」という曲を出しましたが、歌詞は以下のとおりです：

```
頭ごなしに叱らないで
黒い朝日を描いたこと
手付かずのままで残されてしまった
真っ白い絵の具

こんなはずではなかったのと
声が聞こえたら近未来
利き腕が昨日と違うから
上手に握手出来ない

あぁ それでもここに戻るだろう
あぁ 光に引き寄せられるよ
一秒を奪われたままの この場所に

飛んで火に入れ 真夏の虫
見向きもされない希望には
生きてるだけで素晴らしいと
毎日 言って聞かせてる

あぁ それでもここに戻るだろう
あぁ 炎に引き寄せられるよ
一秒を奪われたままの この場所に

あぁ ガラスが石に戻る頃
あぁ 奈落に引き寄せられるよ
一秒が永遠になったままの この場所に
```

聞いた話では、歌詞は紛れもなく原爆の描写だそうです。言われてみれば、確かにイメージは一致すると思いますが、自分が日本人ではないので、その確信の根拠、つまり、他の解釈を除外できる内容とその捉え方がわかりません。また、それが歌詞の全体的な概念とどう関係しているかもわからないので、そこで何かご意見があれば、と思いまして。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず第一に、「紛れもなく原爆」と言えるほどのはっきりとした描写ではないと思います。言われないとほとんど誰も気づかないと思います。原爆の歌だと言われても、まだ解釈が難しいです。

- Sundomeは恐らく[原爆ドーム](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroshima_Peace_Memorial)のことでしょう。
- 「黒い朝日を描く」「白い絵の具」とは、[人影の石](https://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/beta/u/0/asset/%E4%BA%BA%E5%BD%B1%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%B3/OwFsAVq69btaIw?hl=ja)や[はしごと監視兵の写真](http://hero1945.livedoor.biz/archives/50505303.html)の黒い部分と白い部分を指しているのかもしれません。「利き腕が昨日と違う」も関係していそうですが、よくわかりません。
- あるいは「黒い朝日」は原爆の爆発自体を指しているのかもしれません。原爆のfalloutが混じった雨を、俗称で[黒い雨](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BB%92%E3%81%84%E9%9B%A8)と呼ぶので、原爆というと「黒」というイメージはあります。
- 「1秒を奪われた」は、上記の写真の人々が、死ぬことに気づく時間もなく死んでしまったことを指しているのだと思います。教科書に載っている、有名な[ヒロシマ神話](http://hb4.seikyou.ne.jp/home/okinawasennokioku/okinawasentoheiwakyouiku/kokugonojugyou.htm)という詩があり、「"普通の死"の瞬間を奪われた」というのは比較的よく知られている考え方です。

Answer (score 2):

「利き腕が昨日と違うから　上手に握手出来ない」と「一秒を奪われた（永遠になった）」でわかります。

[このYAHOO知恵袋](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1029274335)で語られてる通り、原爆によって壁などが人の陰になった部分を残して黒く焼け焦げることで鏡像の人影ができます。これが「利き腕が昨日とちがう…」とか「一秒を奪われた」ということになります。

歌詞の全体的な概念は私にはわかりません。

（あと、「気に障るつもりはない」とはどういうことでしょうか？「気に障ったら申し訳ないが…」ということでしょうか？）